# PHPMailer Mail Server Name Showing in From Line in Emails Sent

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a website using `PHP 8.1.2`. I'm using `PHPMailer` to send emails. The site is hosted on a Shared Web Hosting server. Everything is working with no errors. But, in the emails that are sent, the name of the mail-server is showing in the `From` line. I.e: `Living Muay Thai via server501.stormwire.com`

I see the same thing when using php's `mail()` method. My guess is this is some sort of default behavior either in `PHP` or in the `mail server`.  Is there a way of preventing the `mail-serer name` from showing when sending emails in `PHP`?

My Code:

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//From email address and name 
$mail->From = "webguy@livingmuaythai.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "Living Muay Thai";
...
...
$mail->send();

//output in email sent
>> Living Muay Thai via server501.stormwire.com
```

Comment: This behaviour indicates that your domain is not sufficiently authenticated; it's not caused by PHP or PHPMailer. You can remove the "via" part by [implementing DKIM](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/dkim-and-the-via-label-in-gmail).

Comment: @Synchro  Thanks, this is something new to me. So, as suggested by my hosting service, I've contacted the party who controls the DNS and ask them to set up the DKIM needed for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Synchro was right.  I use a shared webhosting service: Stormwire.com.  In the Cpanel >> Domans, select the domain and then Manage.

Stormwire has the code I needed to add to remove the `via server501.stormwire.com` from the `From` line in `mail()` emails.

The dns for my domain name is not on stormwire and is owned/controlled by another.  I reached out to that person with the instructions to update the dns.  It is all good now.